# File open on a network share fails on the 6th try using python

Tags: python, windows, server, filesystems

I have a script that writes data to a file share on another server.  I am opening a separate file for separate data sets on a network share and saving it. The issue is that after the 5th file or so in the loop the open fails with:

```
Exception has occurred: OSError[Errno 22] Invalid argument: 
'\\\\file-storage\\storage\\waystar\\active\\ID-143892-Active.txt'
File "D:\AGB\test.py", line 7, in <module>
          with open(fn,'w') as f:
```

I've tried mapping directly to the IP address instead of the network share name. I've tried mapping it to a drive letter on the server. I've created the following test code that reproduces the problem.

```
import os
activedir=r'\\file-storage\storage\waystar\active'
IDs=['123457','123458','123459','143890','143891','143892']
for id in IDs:
    fn=activedir+r'\ID-'+id+'-Active.txt'    
    with open(fn,'w') as f:
        f.write("Hello World - what a bunch of crap.")
```

I'd like to know why it fails on the the last file in the list. The first 5 work correctly and are created. The last one is not and I get the Errno22 as described above.

I added a try block with an except clause that just tries to open the file again. This had a interesting result in the debugger. If I stopped it in the except clause before the open and deleted one of the previously created files, then it would go ahead and create the next file. So there must be some sort of limit stopping me from creating more than 5 files at a time?

```
import os
activedir=r'\\file-storage\storage\waystar\active'
IDs=['123457','123458','123459','143890','143891','143892']
for id in IDs:
    fn=activedir+r'\ID-'+id+'-Active.txt'    
    try:
        with open(fn,'w') as f:
            f.write("Hello World - what a bunch of crap.")
   except:
        with open(fn,'w') as f:
            f.write("Hello World - what a bunch of crap.")
```